# How to save the output of for loop in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a matrix `A` which has a size of 54x100. For some specific condition, I perform an operation on each row of `A`. I need to save the output of this for loop. I've tried the following but it did not work.

```
S=zeros(54,100);
for i=1:54;
   Ri=A(i,:);
   answer=mean(reshape(Ri,5,20),1);
   S(i)=answer;
end
```

Comment: Since you have reshaped your 1x100 vector Ri into a 5x20 one, when computing the mean columnwise you end with `answer` being a 1x20 vector. It's not clear what you try to do, but you cannot reasign this vector into S, since it no longer matches in size.

Answer (score 0):

The output `answer` has shape `1x20` so you should make that the width of `S` like this:

```
S=zeros(54,20);
for i=1:54
   Ri=A(i,:);
   answer=mean(reshape(Ri,5,20),1);
   S(i,:)=answer;
end
```